# Spark plug arcing during removal, engine off.

Tags: engine, electrical, sparkplugs, spark-plug-wires

What could cause the spark plug to arc off the socket and exhaust manifold when removing the spark plug? Obviously the ignition was in the off position.

This same plug tends to get carbon deposits over time. 
I now suspect I may need more grounds.. But the spark plug arcing is weird.

It's a 1993 c1500/Silverado, 4.3l TBI.

Comment: As soon as the socket gets close to the plug it arcs? And then arcs again as you’re removing the plug from the well?

Comment: I only noticed it twice, then disconnected the battery terminal. But it arced with the socket loosely on, which touched the manifold.

Comment: You may have a relay that isn't disengaging... either that or something is something charge... what diagnostics have you done if any?

Comment: No diagnostics yet, I just noticed last night. I do have power going from the battery to the amp (w/ an inline fuse) - just throwing that out. But it has been wired this way for years..

Comment: Is the arching something you can duplicate over and over again?  Is it only 1 spark plug that does it?  Which cylinder is it?  What part of the truck or you leaning on when it happens?  Are you wearing mechanic gloves?  Sorry for all the questions, but your post intrigues me.

Comment: After crawling under neath, I noticed the battery cable to starter is scary close to the manifold.. There is a heat shield, but I wonder if it has cracked over time. It's in an area where I can't see very well, so I'll probably have to drop the starter to disconnect the cable, and pull it out to inspect it closer. I could not duplicate the arcing after fiddling with the cables.

Comment: Inductive kickback from the coil discharging through the plug?

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ the concept. Although, the plug wire was disconnected, not sure if the kickback could still occur as such.

Comment: Did it actually arc e.g. jump a gap or did it throw sparks when you touched the manifold? I would think that if the starter cable was touching anything metal on the engine it would of been obvious for other reasons.